# Session can't find a variable from previous sessions

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm working with multiple files and servlets and I pass a variable as a flag in the following way :

managerPage.jsp :

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>To open a new account</legend> 
  <form action="employeeTransaction1">    
      <input type="hidden" name="hdField" value="managerFlagOn" />
      <input type="submit" value="Press here to continue" />
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Now I go to **employeeTransaction1** servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{


    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    synchronized(session) 
    {
        String hiddenValue = request.getParameter("hdField");

        // then the redirection was made from a Manager's page
        if (hiddenValue.equals("managerFlagOn") == true) 
        {
            session.setAttribute("managerQuery1", hiddenValue);
        }
        // forwards to the page employeeOpenNewAccount.jsp
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/results/employeeOpenNewAccount.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Here I grab the hidden value and place it under the name `managerQuery1` .

Then I'm being forwarded to `employeeOpenNewAccount.jsp`:

**employeeOpenNewAccount.jsp:**

```
<!-- EMPLOYEE OP 1 -  open a new account -->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Employee's transaction page - open a new account</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>


<h1>Employee's transaction page!</h1>
<h1>
Open a new Bank account
</h1>

<!-- from here redirecting to the servelet that's called "employeeOperation1" -->

<fieldset>
  <legend>Please fill the followings</legend>
  <form action="employeeOperation1"> 
    First-name : <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last-name : <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    Address : <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    ID-number : <input type="text" name="idNumber"><br>
    User-name : <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</fieldset>

</body></html>
```

And now I go to `employeeOperation1` servlet :

**employeeOperation1:**

```
@WebServlet("/employeeOperation1")
public class EmployeeServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    synchronized(session) 
    {

       String manager = request.getParameter("managerQuery1");   // the value is null
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

And now the value of `manager`  after grabbing `managerQuery1`  is `null` .

Why is it null ? I thought that session-variables are supposed to stay until the end of the program .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the managerQuery1 in a session attribute, and try to fetch it from a request parameter.

fetch it from the session, and you're done.

```
String manager = session.getAttribute("managerQuery1");
```

Comment: NP, this happens to the best.

Answer (score 1):

```
String manager = session.getAttribute("managerQuery1");
```

**I think you need to cast into String**

```
String manager =(String) session.getAttribute("managerQuery1");
```

**You can follow to get more idea.**

```
  javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

**Once you have done that, you can set a session object like this:**
        session.setAttribute("name","value");

**To retrieve the value, do this:**

```
    String foo = (String) session.getAttribute("name");
```